# What does one call a Morse function whose nondegenerate condition is relaxed?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, morse-theory

In robotics, navigation functions are of utmost interest to plan a path from an initial location $q_0$ to a target location $q^t$. A function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a navigation function if it is Morse, thereby fulfilling all of the conditions below.

1- $f$ is smooth;

2- $f$ is maximal on the boundaries of its domain region;

3- $f$ is minimum at $q = q^t$;

4- all of the critical points of $f$ (including the one located at $q = q^t$) are non-degenerate.

For a specific engineering application, I need to relax the 4th condition, say, $\ddot{f}(q^t) = 0$ is authorized. Obviously, $f$ is no longer Morse. As I am not majoring in mathematics, I don't know whether or not this type of function has been already defined in the mathematical literature. So, what does one call a Morse function whose 4th condition is relaxed? Any reference to the literature is so welcome!

Comment: If you allow only certain types of singularities, I think these are usually just called "generalized Morse functions". They are studied in [Cerf theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerf_theory). For some applications, it's important to consider "framed generalized Morse functions". See for example the work of [Igusa](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2000654?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) and [Eliashberg](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1000).

Comment: Since it must have a minimum, 3 holds true, and only 1 and 2 matters: it's  "a smooth function maximal on the boundary". I don't think that there is a name for such a general class of functions.

Comment: If the critical points form submanifolds, and the Hessian is non-degenerate in the normal directions, then your function is More-Bott, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory These are much studied in the literature.

Comment: A Lesse function?

Comment: Oops, my comment above should say "Morse-Bott" of course!

Comment: @VivekShende: Google search yielded nothing for a "Lesse function" query. Can you cite a reference?